# First time using laravel, could not access public folder

Tags: laravel

I tried to follow step by step and would like to open public folder in the Google browser. I am using xampp, the project folder named as "lsapp". So I typed "localhost/lsapp/public". The error I got is:

"
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
"

Is this related to my antivirus setup or firewalls that stop me from accessing it?

Comment: this can have several causes. one possible solution: clear browser cache. Antivirus programs can also cause this error.

Comment: The `public` folder should not appear in any URL, it should be the project's DocumentRoot. Set up a VirtualHost

Comment: put a  static file like test.html in your public folder and check if you can access it from your browser ˋhttp://lsapp/public/test.htmlˋ. only try this at home.